# jQuery Autocomplete can't display dropdown result (two autocomplete) after changing keyword

Tags: jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have one jquery ui autocomplete input that I would like to show another dropdown after another. For example : If I type two characters of the city name like ba, it would display a dropdown contained : Addis Ababa, Baghdad, Baku, Bamako and Bangkok. If I pick one of them (Bangkok) and press a spacebar, another dropdown (at the same input box) would be displayed : Bangkok Accommodation, Bangkok Restaurants, Bangkok Sights, and Bangkok Transport. I can do this but only for the first time. When I change the keyword like ab. it should display Abu Dhabi, Abuja, etc but the dropdown fail to be displayed. Here is the script :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                var Cities = [
                    'Abu Dhabi',
                    'Abuja',
                    'Accra',
                    'Amsterdam',
                    'Addis Ababa',
                    'Baghdad',
                    'Baku',
                    'Bamako',
                    'Bangkok',
                    'Beijing',
                    'Cairo',
                    'Canberra',
                    'Caracas'
                ];
                $('#dest').autocomplete({
                    source: Cities,
                    minLength: 2,
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        $(this).val(ui.item.value);
                        $(this).blur();
                        $(this).focus();
                        //the second autocomplete
                        var more=[
                            ui.item.value + ' Accommodation',
                            ui.item.value + ' Restaurants',
                            ui.item.value + ' Sights',
                            ui.item.value + ' Transport'
                        ];
                        $('#dest').autocomplete({
                            source: more,
                            select: function (event, ui) {
                                $(this).val(ui.item.value);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <span><em><strong>City</strong></em></span>
            <br />
            <span><input type="text" id="dest" name="dest" value="" placeholder="Type the name of the city ... " /></span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I dont want to use another input box for this.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lngzbjc6/5/

Answer (score 0):

After many trying, I got the solution (I dont know if this is the best). Here is the full code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                var Cities = [
                    'Abu Dhabi',
                    'Abuja',
                    'Accra',
                    'Amsterdam',
                    'Addis Ababa',
                    'Baghdad',
                    'Baku',
                    'Bamako',
                    'Bangkok',
                    'Beijing',
                    'Cairo',
                    'Canberra',
                    'Caracas'
                ];
                $('#dest').autocomplete({
                    source: Cities,
                    minLength: 2,
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        $(this).val(ui.item.value);
                        $('#temp_val').val(ui.item.value);
                        $(this).blur();
                        $(this).focus();
                        //the second autocomplete
                        var more=[
                            ui.item.value + ' Accommodation',
                            ui.item.value + ' Restaurants',
                            ui.item.value + ' Sights',
                            ui.item.value + ' Transport'
                        ];
                        $('#dest').autocomplete({
                            source: more,
                            select: function (event, ui) {
                                $(this).val(ui.item.value);
                                $('#temp_val').val(ui.item.value);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
                $('#dest').keypress(function(event){
                    var dest = $.trim($('#dest').val());
                    var temp_val = $.trim($('#temp_val').val());

                    if(temp_val != ''){
                        if(event.which != 32)
                            $('#dest').autocomplete('option','source',Cities);
                        else{
                            var arr=[' Accommodation',' Restaurants',' Sights',' Transport'];
                            var found_arr='';
                            $.each(arr,function(index,value){
                                if(temp_val.indexOf(value) >= 0){
                                    found_arr=value;
                                    return false;
                                }
                            });
                            if(found_arr != '')
                                temp_val=temp_val.replace(found_arr,'');
                            var more=[
                                temp_val + ' Accommodation',
                                temp_val + ' Restaurants',
                                temp_val + ' Sights',
                                temp_val + ' Transport'
                            ];
                            $('#dest').autocomplete('option','source',more);
                        }   
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <span><em><strong>City</strong></em></span>
            <br />
            <span><input type="text" id="dest" name="dest" value="" placeholder="Type the name of the city ... " /></span>
            <input type="hidden" id="temp_val" name="temp_val" value="">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```